# Would managing div widths with jquery be a good idea?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a client which want a css tricky solution. They want the divs to have different widths on different occasions. Like on page 1 we have a leftnavigation, on page 2 we don't. So the content containing divs should expand in width when the leftnavigation div is not there.

html

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="leftnav"></div>
        <div class="contentColumnLeft"></div>
        <div class="contentColumnRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#page{width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#wrapper{margin: 0px auto; width: 960px;}
.leftnav{width: 110px; float: left;}
.contentColumnLeft{width: 500px; float: left;}
.contentColumnRight{width: 200px; float: left;}
```

When the .leftnav is not there (gets removed with jquery when page url contains parameters `?lnav=t`) it leaves a wide gap open on the right side of the #wrapper div which I want to close.

Can this be solved CSS wise or is jquery a valid second option?

Comment: Why do you remove left nav with js? There are no backend coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

```
#wrapper{display: table;}
.leftnavn{display: table-cell;}
.contentColumnLeft{display: table-cell;}
.contentColumnRight{display: table-cell;}
```

Then when the leftnav gets removed from inside the #wrapper, the others will always take up the remaining space.

Check out [this demo to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/3npuH/1/).

Click the `.leftnavn` div to see the other two divs take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

```
#page{width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#wrapper{margin: 0px auto; width: 960px;background:black;overflow:hidden}
.leftnav{width: 110px; float: left;background:yellow;}
.contentColumnLeft{min-width: 500px; background:green;overflow:hidden}
.contentColumnRight{width: 200px; float: right;background:red;}
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/zUrrJ/

Now when you put `display:none` in your `.leftnav` then `.contentColumnLeft` expand

Answer (score 0):

No. You know what layout you will want on the server, so you can set class names there and avoid:

- Depending on JS
- A delay before the JS runs and the styling kicks in